# How to stub the Entity Manager in Nest.js and jest, for unit test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

Hello I want to stub the Entity manager in typeorm. I am doing the unit test. Whenever I stub the getManager() I got connection not found error. Is there any suitable solution to stub the Entity Manager.
The function is given below, for which I want to do a unit test.

// function to be tested

```
async createStore(dto: ServiceCreateDto): Promise<ServiceDto> {

  // create the Service entity
  let entity: ServiceEntity;

  try {

    await getManager().transaction(async transaction => {

      entity = transaction.create(ServiceEntity, dto)
  
      // save the new entity
      await transaction.save(entity);
      this.logger.log(`created new Service with serviceId: ${entity.id}`);
      
    });
    return entity;

  } catch (error) {
      throw error;
  }
}
```